# Command to list permission of file and all folders from root to the file's path

Tags: linux

Given a file, say `/var/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/some_dir_3/some_file`, 
is there a single command that will list the permissions of `some_file` and all the directories in its path from root, i.e. the permissions for `var`, `some_dir_1`, `some_dir_2`, `some_dir_3`?

Comment: duplicate of [How can I list permissions of every component in a file path?](https://superuser.com/questions/685576/how-can-i-list-permissions-of-every-component-in-a-file-path)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `namei` with `-l` (long) on an absolute path:

```
namei -l /absolute/path/to/file
```

It will give you something like:

```
dr-xr-xr-x root  root   /
drwxr-xr-x root  root   absolute
drwx------ user1 group1 path
drwxr-xr-x user1 group1 to
-rw-r--r-- user1 group1 file
```

You must provide full path. If you don't want to type it you can use `realpath` or `readlink`.

```
namei -l $(readlink -m relative_path_to/file)
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, and thanks for updating an old question with an even better answer!

Comment: `-l` doesn't work on RHEL5.6

Answer (score 2):

The following `bash` script prints all permissions of the directory entry passed as argument and all its parents up to `/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || exit 1

FILEPATH="$1"

while true ; do
    ls -ld "$FILEPATH"
    [[ "$FILEPATH" != "/" ]] || exit
    FILEPATH="$( dirname "$FILEPATH" )"
done
```

Save as e.g. `parent_permissions.sh` and run using `/path/to/parent_permissions.sh /path/to/file`.

It only works with absolute paths unless combined with `readlink -f` or the [`abspath` script from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/205133/22317), in which case you need to change the initial assignment of `FILEPATH` to:

```
FILEPATH="$( abspath "$1" )"
```

On Linux, this might work (untested):

```
FILEPATH="$( readlink -f "$1" )"
```

Example output:

```
drwxr-xr-x  66 danielbeck  staff  2244  2 Feb 12:38 /Users/danielbeck
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  admin  374  1 Feb 15:21 /Users
drwxrwxr-t  35 root  admin  1258 22 Jan 23:09 /
```

Add arguments to the `ls` call, or replace it e.g. with `getfacl`, as appropriate on your system to print ACLs and extended attributes if you're interested in them.