# How can I list permissions of every component in a file path?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, path, acl

Sometimes it is necessary to determine on which directory in a path access rights are limited. Here is an example:

```
$ ls /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
ls: cannot access /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices: Permission denied
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices: Permission denied
```

Neither `ls` nor `cat` shows where the user rights were limited.

What is the simplest way of showing the access rights for every component (directory and the file) in the path? I am mainly interested in solutions for Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For basic UNIX permissions (owner/group/other), use `namei` which is part of *util-linux*:

```
# namei -l /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
f: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
drwxr-xr-x root root /
dr-xr-xr-x root root sys
drwxr-xr-x root root kernel
drwx------ root root debug
drwxr-xr-x root root usb
-r--r--r-- root root devices
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple Bourne-like-shell script. It traverses the path by gradual removing of the last components using the `dirname` command until the path stops changing. You get either `/` or `.` at the end.

```
#!/bin/sh

f="$1"
p=
while test "$f" != "$p" ; do
    ls -ld "$f"
    p="$f"
    f="$(dirname "$f")"
done
```

In a single line with `sudo` to be able to see components with limited access rights:

```
f=/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices p= ; while test "$f" != "$p" ; do sudo ls -ld "$f" ; p="$f" ; f="$(dirname "$f")" ; done
```

### Example output

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 10:36 /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Dec  5 10:36 /sys/kernel/debug/usb
drwx------ 19 root root 0 Dec  5 10:36 /sys/kernel/debug
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 0 Dec  5 10:37 /sys/kernel
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Dec  5 10:37 /sys
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Dec  3 09:39 /
```

### POSIX ACL

If the permission string from `ls -l` shows `+` at the end you have to list ACL using `getfacl` to see the complete access rights:

```
#!/bin/sh

f="$1"
p=
while test "$f" != "$p" ; do
    getfacl "$f"
    p="$f"
    f="$(dirname "$f")"
done
```