# Mac OS X .bashrc not working

Tags: macos, bash, bashrc

I have a one-line `.bashrc` file in my home directory:

```
alias countlines='find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l'
```

But it is not creating the alias.  Why might that be?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

In OSX, `.bash_profile` is used instead of `.bashrc`.

And yes, the `.bash_profile` file should be located in `/Users/YourName/`
(In other words, `~/.bash_profile`)

For example, `/Users/Aaron/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is not the right answer. Aliases are not inherited, so, if you only define them in .bash_profile, they won't be defined in non-login shells (eg when you run bash inside bash).

Comment: Or one can use bash_aliases which has the same effect as putting the aliases in bashrc, but more manageable: http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html

Comment: in my .bash_profile I just wrote one line to alias (sort of ) bashrc -> `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: a girl almost threw the mac at me for arguing blindly that placing anything in ~/.bashrc on will work.

Comment: @EricHodonsky is living in 2030. You're a lion amongst sheep.

Comment: saved my life, I thought I lost this file.

Answer (score 115):

`.[bash_]profile` and `.bashrc` can be used on both OS X and Linux. The former is loaded when the shell is a login shell; the latter when it is not. The real difference is that Linux runs a login shell when the user logs into a graphical session, and then, when you open a terminal application, those shells are non-login shells; whereas OS X does not run a shell upon graphical login, and when you run a shell from Terminal.app, that is a login shell.

If you want your aliases to work in both login and non-login shells (and you usually do), you should put them in .bashrc *and* source .bashrc in your .bash_profile, with a line like this:

```
[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc
```

This applies to any system using bash.

Comment: +1 with the caveat that everything in .bashrc will be run again for sub-shells (and subsub-, subsubsub-, etc), so e.g. `PATH=$PATH:/my/private/binaries` will lead to PATH bloat.  See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there/39995#39995) for a workaround.

Comment: True. Since exported instance variables are inherited, I just set them in `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`.

Comment: @LaC can you explain _Since exported instance variables are inherited, I just set them in `.profile_`…?

Comment: @sam, I don't know where "instance" came from. I just meant "exported variables". Unfortunately I cannot edit that comment.

Comment: I know what ```source ~/.bashrc``` does; but what does ```[ -r ~/.bashrc ]``` do, and is it necessary?

Comment: @dinosaur: "-r" checks if the file is readable.

Comment: ...pertinently for the current situation, *exists* and is readable, so if there is no `~/.bashrc`, that check prevents an error being caused by trying to `source` a nonexisting file.

Answer (score 19):

Since **MacOS Catalina** `zsh` is the default shell. On this OS add the alias into `~/.zshrc`

Pre **Catalina** add the alias to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: This worked for me on Big Sur. Terminal is using zsh.

Comment: This worked for me on Ventura.

Answer (score 9):

Or create a sym link called .bash_profile pointed at your .bashrc

```
ln -s .bashrc .bash_profile
```

Comment: On newer versions of OS X, the terminal may be using ZSH, which means `.zshrc` should be used instead of `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 9):

I tried using the solution to update .*bash_profile* and *.bashrc* but that did not work because MacOS >= `10.15` (Catalina) is using zsh as default.

So:

- create a new file, `~/.zprofile`, add aliases there.
- use command `source ~/.zprofile` to execute in same shell or just open a new terminal.

and your changes should be permament.

Comment: command 'source ~/.zprofile' just executes your code in bashrc or zprofile.

Answer (score 3):

It is not being aliased because `.bash_profile` is used instead of `.bashrc` on Mac OS X.

So you have two options:

- Put the alias in your `~/.bash_profile`
- Or source your `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` by adding this line to the `.bash_profile`:

  `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

On **Mac OS X Yosemite**, run the following command:

```
vi ~/.profile
```

Then add the following line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now save and close `.profile`, then open a new Terminal window or just run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

See also [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically/13025#13025). It worked on v10.10.3.

Comment: This is little more than a rehash of the answers from four years ago.

Comment: Sure, just an easy eay to read and apply it. Plus a small contribution - since the other mentioned files were not available on my OS Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS, you might be using the Z shell. To check, type:

`echo $0`

See if the output is `-zsh`. If so, you need to add your lines into `~/.zshrc`

Comment: The question has already been answered and accepted and it was not zsh.