# Shell function in .bashrc is not recognized

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, alias

I know this must be something silly but somehow I am stuck trying to create a shortcut (alias) for a shell function.

Here is my exact `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
alias l="ls -G"
r () {
   echo "iron_worker upload $1"
   echo "iron_worker queue $1"
}
export -f r
```

So I've added my function `r()` at the end of the file. Now when I type `r` in the shell, I still get error:

```
-bash: r: command not found
```

I have restarted terminal, shell window, and still no effect.

I am on Mac OS 10.8.5 if that matters.

EDIT.

After some searching found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/244964/mac-os-x-bashrc-not-working/) suggesting to use `bash_profile` instead of `bashrc`, which is now working! But ... what I get are the commands listed but not executed:

```
Dmitris-MacBook-Pro:~ dmitrizaitsev$ r
iron_worker upload 
iron_worker queue
```

This the normal command execution that I expected:

```
Dmitris-MacBook-Pro:~ dmitrizaitsev$ iron_worker upload
Please specify code package name or path to workerfile
usage: iron_worker upload CODE_PACKAGE_NAME_OR_PATH_TO_WORKERFILE [OPTIONS]
    -n, --name NAME                  override code name
    -c CONCURRENCY,                  max number of concurrent workers for this code package
        --max-concurrency
    -r, --retries NUM_RETRIES        max number of automatic retries on task fail
    -d RETRIES_DELAY,                delay between each automatic retry
        --retries-delay
        --worker-config CONFIG_FILE  config file for worker
    -h, --host HOST                  host name, eg: www.mydomain.com
    -a, --async                      don't wait for package build
        --full-remote-build          activate full remote build
        --config CONFIG              config file
    -e, --env ENV                    environment
        --project-id PROJECT_ID      project id
Dmitris-MacBook-Pro:~ dmitrizaitsev$
```

Instead I am only getting the command and nothing else.
Any idea what is going on?

Comment: try sourcing your .bashrc file

Comment: @MariusMatutiae The file is in my user directory `~/` and the content is as in the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is: sh .bashrc

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Did that - still the same result :(

Comment: lol which shell are you using right now?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae `bash` - like in the error message above

Comment: Try putting the def of r, and the export, in another, executable file, then execute that file. if it works, put the command that executes that file inside .bashrc

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Put into `.alias`, `chmod a+x`, executed, no effect

Comment: Remove the word `function`

Comment: To check that this works, you must use a different shell that you have started `after` you sourced your .bashrc, so that it can have inherited the niew function. In staler shells, this will not work.

Comment: It is working exactly as expected: you did not pass arguments to r, so none appears; you wanted r to print some stuff, it did. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use, inside the same file, the line:

```
   export -f r
```

To check that this works, you must use a different shell that you have started `after` you sourced your .bashrc, so that it can have inherited the new function. In staler shells, this will not work.

Also, insert this in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       source ~/.bashrc
   fi
```

If you wish to run the program iron_worker, then the body of the function r should be:

```
   r () {
   iron_worker upload $1
   iron_worker queue $1
   }
```

Also, I suggest you provide the full pathname to the command iron_worker (i.e. substitute `iron_worker` with `/path/to/iron_worker`).

Comment: Added and still no effect. Also noticed that aliases like `alias l="ls"` inside the same file don't work either :(

Comment: Ok, I figured I need to `source .bashrc`, then it works. But it isn't automatically activated in the new shell unless I do it again :( Is there a way to source it automatically?

Comment: Somehow what I get is the opposite - it works in the same window after sourcing but not in a new one.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev pls check my new edit.

Comment: Please see my edit - maybe the function definition is a problem?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev see my edit

Comment: Now enjoying my function, really appreciate help.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev   It's a pleasure to be of some help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal and iTerm open new shells as login shells by default, so bash reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`.

You can either:

- Use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.
- Add `. ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`.
- Make new shells open with a non-login shell, by for example changing "Shells open with" from "Default login shell" to the command `/bin/bash` in Terminal.

I have done the last two. For example tmux and the shell mode in Emacs open new login shells as non-login shells by default. `~/.bash_profile` is still read when I ssh to my computer.

See https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html for more information.

The `function` keyword in your function definition is redundant by the way. `function name() { :; }` is identical to `name() { :; }` in bash. The `function` keyword is not defined by POSIX.